# How to render a partial view on another view in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

When I tried alert("Hi") in `renderMoreView` function, it actually works, but to display the View is the problem I am facing

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    moreButton: false,
  };

  renderMoreView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, height: 50, width: 50}}>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        .....
        <TouchableOpacity
          underlayColor="transparent"
          onPress={() => this.setState ({moreButton: true})}
        >
          <Feather name="more-vertical" size={25} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        ...
        {this.state.moreButton ? this.renderMoreView () : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[This is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7HOa.jpg)]

Comment: try adding `position: absolute, top: 10, left: 10` to the moreView

Comment: Can you remove flex style in your view?  And make your backgroundcolor white for see text clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you could use `Modal` component. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `modal`. But if you want to do it more simply, install and use the module. `react-native-awesome-alerts`

1. `$ npm i react-native-awesome-alerts --save`

### Example

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showAlert: false };
  };

  showAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true
    });
  };

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {showAlert} = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>I'm AwesomeAlert</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          this.showAlert();
        }}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Try me!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <AwesomeAlert
          show={showAlert}
          showProgress={false}
          title="AwesomeAlert"
          message="I have a message for you!"
          closeOnTouchOutside={true}
          closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
          showCancelButton={true}
          showConfirmButton={true}
          cancelText="No, cancel"
          confirmText="Yes, delete it"
          confirmButtonColor="#DD6B55"
          onCancelPressed={() => {
            this.hideAlert();
          }}
          onConfirmPressed={() => {
            this.hideAlert();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#AEDEF4",
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15
  }
});
```

[image]